# Requests stalled in Chrome and Firefox for 2 seconds (windows 7)

Tags: node.js, angular, google-chrome, request, stalled

I locally start an angular application ant try to load it. It loads quite a lot of js/css files (xhr requests).
Sometimes everything goes right, but most of the time 1-3 requests (js or css files) get stuck for exactly 2 minutes (they are in "stalled" state in chrome).
During this pause no other file is loaded. After they are finally loaded, the loading of the rest of application continues.

The applicaiton gets loaded after 2.5 - 4.5 minutes (depending if there was one or two pauses).

The similar issue is on Firefox and Opera. The only browser that gets it right (loads the app in a few seconds 90% of times) is Internet Explorer.

I've tried changing the maximum connections to one host (on firefox) from the default 6 to different values - it didn't work.
I tried disabling the firewalls - it didn't change anything.

Other people in the team (usually using windows 10) don't have the problem. But we've seen something similar on another computer with windows 10.
Since the issu is only on one/two workspaces, I suppose that it's the environment settings that needs to be adjusted.

I've checked chrome events. Every time the request gets stalled (and only then):
- HTTP_TRANSACTION_READ_HEADERS / HTTP_STEAM_PARSER_READ_HEADERS receives "net_error = -100 (ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED)".
Then one HTTP_STEAM_JOB_CONTROLLER is fired for this request... and exactly 2 minutes later another one is fired. After this one is finished, the page is loaded correctly.
The second job uses a different socket. The socket that received -100 error is never used again.

I suppose that the connection is closed by the system, the browser doesn't know about it and waits for a response... and after a timeout of 2 minutes it uses another connection.

Any ideas how can I solve this issue?
I'm waiting for a few minutes for the page to load, when it should load in 5 seconds.

Environment:
- Node v6.11.0
- Npm 3.10.10
- gulp 3.9.1
- gulp-server-livereload 1.9.2
- Chrome 59.0.3071.115 (64 bit)
- Windows 7 Professional SP1 (64 bit)

**UPDATE:**
In chrome dev tools / Network tab I changed the "no throttling" to "wifi". With this workaround settings the problem is very rare (most of the time the site loads in around 6 sec).

It looks like we hit some kind of connection limit if the browser tries to execute too many requests too quickly (maybe some max requests per second limit on the system/node level?)

Comment: Is there any more information I could provide to help identify the problem?

Comment: Any ideas? The problem still exists...